# How to seek to kafka record from starting after an API call in spring boot webservice

Tags: spring-kafka

I have a spring-boot Kafka project which is a web-service exposing API to get Kafka message in response.
What i want is whenever i call the rest end point the Kafka should start searching from beginning it does it as i used earliest in auto-reset config but i have to start server again and again to make it listen to Kafka from starting.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"topic"})
public void storeMessagesMessages(ConsumerRecord record) {

    if (record.value().toString().contains(uuid) {
        this.messageToBeReturnedByApi = record.value()
    }
}
```

Or i can say i want this listener part to be invoked only when i call web service endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Your listener should extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`; you can then perform arbitrary seek operations. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#seek